# Fetching all Microsoft Active Directory users in Domino Xpages NamePicker via java Agent

Tags: active-directory, ldap, xpages, javaagents

I'm working with LDAP Microsoft Active Directory and Domino server and quite new with this.

we've successfully fetched all Microsoft Active Directory users in Domino via java Agent and have printed all the user names in java debug console. For that referred this http://lotus-blogs.blogspot.in/2009/08/ldap-programming-using-domino-java-step.html link.

Now, i want to get all users in Domino Xpages NamePicker, so is this possible to get all users in Xpages NamePicker via java Agent?

As per we see that in Xpages NamePicker, we are able to fetch the Domino Users with the help of java beans.

Any kind of suggestion will be really Appreciated.

My java Agent is like following-

```
import lotus.domino.*;

public class JavaAgent extends AgentBase {

    public void NotesMain() {

      try {
          Session session = getSession();
          AgentContext agentContext = session.getAgentContext();

          LDAPQuery.ldapconnect();

      } catch(Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
}
```

AND

```
import javax.naming.*;
import javax.naming.directory.*;
import java.util.*;

public class LDAPQuery {

public static void ldapconnect(){

String isFound="0";

try {

    System.out.println("inside try 1");
Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "PROVIDER_URL");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "UserName");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");
// Create initial context
DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env); 
// Specify the ids of the attributes to return 
String[] attrIDs = {"cn","mail"};
SearchControls ctls = new SearchControls();
ctls.setReturningAttributes(attrIDs);
ctls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

String filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(mail=*abc.com))";
System.out.println("filter defined");
// Search for objects that have those matching attributes
NamingEnumeration answer = ctx.search("", filter,ctls);

System.out.println("get the answer!");
try { 

    System.out.println("inside try2");
while (answer.hasMore())
{
SearchResult sr = (SearchResult)answer.next();
System.out.println("<<" + sr.getName()+">>");
Attributes attrs = sr.getAttributes();
//System.out.println(sr.getName().matches("/^[0-9]/"));
System.out.println(attrs.get("cn").get());
System.out.println(attrs.get("mail").get());
isFound="1";
}

if ( isFound=="1") {
System.out.println("User found in Active Directory!"); 
} else {
System.out.println("Opps ! User not found in Active Directory!"); 
} 
answer.close();
}catch(PartialResultException e) {

    System.out.println("catch 2");
e.printStackTrace();
}
// Close the context when we're done
ctx.close();
} catch (Exception e) {

    System.out.println("catch 1");
e.printStackTrace();
}

}

public LDAPQuery() {
// Don't think I'm doing anything here
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried your code? Did you run into problems? If so, what are they?

Comment: we have run the code , we have printed all the usernames in java debug console, all the usernames all printed properly as required. But the the problem is to get these names to name picker. as name picker only has the bean option but in our case it is the java agent which is providing the names .

Answer (score 1):

OK, got it.

Any particular reason why you are utilizing an Agent as opposed to using a true bean? Calling an agent everytime someone opens the name picker in my opinion is far from being effective.

Apart from that I don't see a way how the results from your agent could directly be passed into the name picker.

Third: looking at your ldap filter I'm sure that your code will return hundreds or even thousands of names. Using a standard ExtLib NamePicker is no fun for your users, believe me: the list of names displayed per dialog page is way too limited. But that may be a different story.

Sticking to the namePicker approach there are several ways how you could achieve what you appear to accomplish:

1. refactor your java agent into a javaBean then feed the result to the control
2. consider going for a directory syncing tool like IBM TDI; thus your AD data can be pushed into a Domino directory of your choice, and then from within your application you can utilize standard name lookup features